# Attach click listener to a jQueryUI button in a buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Attempting to attach a click listener to all of the buttons in a buttonset:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="options">
  <input class="optionCtrl" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="Yes" />
  <label for="radio1"> True </label>
  <input class="optionCtrl" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="No" />
  <label for="radio2"> False </label>
  <input class="optionCtrl" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="Maybe" />
  <label for="radio3"> Don’t know </label>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$("#options").buttonset();
$('.optionCtrl').click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

But no dice. Using the Chrome developer console, it looks like jQueryUI is replacing the `input` element with the `label` element and a `span` element - attaching the click to the label didn't work either. Any pointers?

Comment: It seems to work for me. Does this jsFiddle work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/PEcX9/

Comment: Yes it does - figured it out in the answer I posted, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue related to the fact that the buttonset in question was in a Goole Maps infowindow. I needed to switch the click listener to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so that when the infowindow is created and the button content added, the click listener works.